# SharePoint 2013 Workflow - Automatically goes to 'Canceled' state

Tags: 2013, workflow, error, sharepoint-server

Once I deploy the VS 2012 workflow and create a new List Item which will trigger the workflow.

First I see is this Status

[image]

Then after few seconds I see the Internal Status changing to 'Canceled'.

Any idea why this is happening??

Comment: What are you trying to do in this workflow?

Comment: @Aanchal to start off just a single 'writeToHistory' is performed with a static string message.

Comment: Do you get any error in 15 hive logs?

Comment: @Aanchal Looking into it now..

Comment: @Aanchal found this - 'Failed to get ApplicationUserCredentials, switching to ApplicationCredentials for System Account.'

Comment: Please check site collection features. There is feature called Workflow can use app permissions. Activate that.

Comment: Just saw that in a post as well... Let me see whether that was the culprit :)

Comment: also check http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/74f34eb3-dbb5-4ca7-a18f-f18a9c23652d/sharepoint-2013-workflow-status-is-always-canceled and http://anujabhojani.blogspot.in/2013/02/sharepoint-2013-workflow-gets-canceled.html

Comment: This worked Alhamdulillah :-)!! Thanks you @Aanchal :-)!!

Comment: Mark this as answer so that other member can get help.

Comment: @Aanchal Will do... Isn't it a Site Feature than a site collection feature?

Comment: Site feature it is

Comment: Carlos, What do you mean that you had a duplicated column? Did you have 2 Columns with the same display name in the list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check site features. There is feature called "Workflow can use app permissions". Activate that.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj822159(v=office.15).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj822159%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Comment: Site Collection Features or Site Features??

Comment: In addition, check whether the 'App Management Service' is running! else start it from the CAW Manage services page.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had a duplicate column who's value was used in the workflow. Delete it and created a new one (with a new name). This resolved issue.